# Rest Post call with Authentication Token

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to send a Post request to SharePoint Online (Claims Based Auth Site) from my client application (WPF application). In this case it should be an update to a ListItem to change the 'Title' to 'Test'.

I'm retrieving the CookieContainer via [MsOnlineClaimsHelper Class](https://github.com/rmorg/SPFunnelback/blob/master/SharePoint%20Test%20Scripts/C%23/Wictor.Office365.ClaimsDemo/MsOnlineClaimsHelper.cs)
which successfully returns me an auth token.

But when i try to send the request the response is `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

**WebRequest Code**

```
try
{
    var claimshelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(baseUrl, _userName, _password);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUrl + "/" + url);

    request.CookieContainer = claimshelper.CookieContainer;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
    request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    var webResp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    var theData = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), true);
    string payload = theData.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{


}
```

**Rest Url:**

`/_api/lists/getbytitle('SampleList')/items(1)`

**Json Payload:**

```
string json = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.SampleListListItem' }, 'Title': 'Test'}";
```

**Error:**

`The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs since SharePoint 2013 REST service **requires** the user to include a `Request Digest` value with each `create`, `update` and `delete` operation. This value is then used by SharePoint to identify non-genuine requests.

### How to provide Request Digest value

In `MsOnlineClaimsHelper class` (`MsOnlineClaimsHelper.cs` file) add the following method to request Form Digest value:

```
/// <summary>
/// Request Form Digest value
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private string GetFormDigest()
{
    var endpoint = "/_api/contextinfo";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_host.AbsoluteUri + endpoint);

    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.Method = "POST";
    //request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    request.ContentLength = 0;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

             // parse the ContextInfo response
             var resultXml = XDocument.Parse(result);

             // get the form digest value
             var e = from e in resultXml.Descendants()
                                 where e.Name == XName.Get("FormDigestValue", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")
                            select e;
             _formDigest = e.First().Value;   
         }
    }
    return _formDigest;
}
```

and `FormDigest` property:

```
private string _formDigest;
public string FormDigest
{
    get
    {
       if (_formDigest == null || DateTime.Now > _expires)
       {
           return GetFormDigest();
       }
       return _formDigest;
    }
}
```

### How to perform an update operation for a ListItem using SharePoint 2013 REST API

The following example demonstrates how to perform an update of a list item using the provided implementation for requesting a Form Digest

Key Points:

- `X-RequestDigest` header is used to specify Form Digest value
- Request `Content Type` have to be specified

Example:

```
var userName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "password";
var payload = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' }, 'Title': 'New Tasl'}";  //for a Task Item


try
{
    var claimshelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(baseUrl, _userName, _password);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseUrl + "/" + endpointUrl);

    request.CookieContainer = claimshelper.CookieContainer;
    request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", claimshelper.FormDigest);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
    request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(payload);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    //...
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    //Error handling goes here.. 
 }
```

Comment: I get a crisis that it was so easy. I thougth you have to send already an ContextToken with the call to `_api/contextinfo` like stated on Msdn `Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`. Thank you very much. It worked for the first time with my damn post request ;)